# HTML Form: POST an array of objects

Tags: html, arrays, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

Submitting a class roster.  Adding 3 students at once.  Each student has first, last, age.

**Question:**  How can we get all of the students in an array of arrays?

```
students[0] => Array (
  ["first"] => "first name for 0",
  ["last"] => "last name for 0",
  ["age"] => "age for 0"
),
students[1] => Array (
  ["first"] => "first name for 1",
  ["last"] => "last name for 1",
  ["age"] => "age for 1"
), 
...
```

**Details**
For one student:

```
<input type="text" name="first">  
<input type="text" name="last">  
<input type="text" name="age">
```

We can return multiple students in separate arrays like this:

```
<input type="text" name="students[first][]">  
<input type="text" name="students[last][]">  
<input type="text" name="students[age][]">
```

which returns an array of firsts, lasts and ages

```
students["first"] = [array of first names]
students["last"] = [array of last names]
students["age"] = [array of ages]
```

Theoretically we can get all the info for a student by accessing the same index (say "3" for each array).

We do not want to programatically add an index in the form.
Do not want:

```
<input type="text" name="students[hardcoded_index][first]">  
<input type="text" name="students[hardcoded_index][last]">  
<input type="text" name="students[hardcoded_index][age]">
```

If for any reason it matters, we are using Rails for views but can use form helpers or HTML.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

## tl;dr: Add empty brackets (`[]`) after `students` to the input names.

Fiddling with [Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rack/Rack/Utils.parse_nested_query) it seems you can get the payload you want like this:

```
<!-- first student -->
<input type="text" name="students[][first]">
<input type="text" name="students[][last]">
<input type="text" name="students[][age]">

<!-- second student -->
<input type="text" name="students[][first]">
<input type="text" name="students[][last]">
<input type="text" name="students[][age]">
```

**Note the empty brackets (`[]`) after `students`.** This tells Rack you want the `students` param to be an array. Subsequent params encountered (with the same name) will start a new element.

`POST /myroute?students[][first]=foo&students[][last]=bar&students[][age]=21&students[][first]=baz&students[][last]=qux&students[][age]=19`

Gets parsed like this:

```
{"students" => [
  {
    "first" => "foo",
     "last" => "bar",
      "age" => "21"
  },
  {
    "first" => "baz",
     "last" => "qux",
      "age" => "19"
  }
]}
```

Further reading: http://codefol.io/posts/How-Does-Rack-Parse-Query-Params-With-parse-nested-query

Comment: I don't know what Flask is, but probably not. This answer is specific to Ruby on Rails.

Comment: I am using Rails4. This approach made the HTTP POST request correctly with all the students info (as i confirmed from the chrome network inspector). But inside the `controller.create` method (using binding.pry), when i see `params` it shows an array of the students but contains ONLY one hash in it - only the last student's hash - the previous students are missing inside the params. What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: For those using Django & DRF, the format required is `students[0]first` (no dot, unique, specified indexes) as I finally found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57013811/3507333

Answer (score 22):

> I know the question is old , but I would like to add my experiences
>   also for future readers.

For those of you who want to **process the data** in a PHP enviroment ,
@messanjah's method won't work ,

The methods for parsing data like the built-in `serializeArray` or `serialize` are not parsing it as expected either.

This is what I tried so far ...

- `students[name]`
- `students[][name]` - *Very Strange since it was meant to automatically index the array*
- `students[name][]`

Neither of them worked, but this `students[<hardcoded-index>][name]` worked for **PHP** ,

> I know that *although the question is against this method* , but it
>   will be useful for PHP users who will land here in the nearby future
>   as the asker needed it for Ruby On Rails.

The **method** you choose to hard code the indexes is upto you , you can use a cleaner method by using **javascript** or you can **manually hard cod**e them initially in your form element.

Cheers

Comment: This is very interesting. Does this imply the difficulty surrounding this particular task is not a rails specific thing, but a HTML thing?

Comment: Exactly! - but I believe the problem is already solved by now or at least a workaround is available more prettier than this one :D

Comment: i hope so, it’s a little confusing for me, but still a great help. If you know I’d any newer techniques please share the link