# How to send a boolean value by GM_xmlhttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, php, greasemonkey

I have a problem with form in Greasemonkey .
I want to send a boolean value usign GM_xmlhttpRequest, but if I send:

```
GM_xmlhttpRequest({
  method: "POST",
  url: "http://localhost/test.php",
  data: "confirm=true",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  },
  onload: function(response) {
    console.log(response.responseText);
  }
});
```

Test php:

```
var_dump( $_POST );
```

At the console I see:

> array(1) {   ["confirm"]=>   string(4) "true" }

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Your server side will need to interpret the value and convert it into the data type you want.  All data passed to the server comes in as a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just convert the value to Boolean on the server side - you already have the value.

You can either do a straight `$myVar = $_POST["confirm"] === "true";`

or use `filter_var` with the `FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN` flag, to cover more options:

`$myVar = filter_var($_POST["confirm"], FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN);` - this allows you to cover `true`, `TRUE`, `on`, `yes`, etc. - all interpreted as Boolean `true`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I wanted to test this because on the webpage in my job I've checked the network bookmark and I saw :

Comment: searchIds:["237thff66"]
search:true

Comment: type of them in chrome :array and boolean

Comment: And I want to know,how it is possible ?

Comment: How can I send the array by post method. Array ,not string

Comment: I don't see how is this connected to the original question, but you might want to look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34313657/html-form-post-an-array-of-objects

Answer (score 0):

Since you're sending the data in as JSON, all you need to do is decoding the post value similar to:

```php
$var = json_decode($_POST['some_param']);
```

This way you'll get the correct type.