# How to bind multipart/form-data array in Echo framework?

Tags: go, go-echo

I'm writing an api server using flutter and Go Echo framework, I want to send data from flutter to Go and save it, but `c.bind()` doesn't work in Go:

```
type _getData struct {
    Title    string      `json:"title" form:"title"`
    Address  string      `json:"address" form:"address"`
    Location string      `json:"location" form:"location"`
    MapId    uint        `json:"map_id" form:"map_id"`
    Date     _customTime `json:"date" form:"date"`
    Pages    []struct {
        Order       int    `json:"order" form:"order"`
        Description string `json:"description" form:"description"`
    } `json:"pages" form:"pages"`
    Tags []struct {
        TagName string `json:"tag_name" form:"tag_name"`
        ID      string `json:"id" form:"id"`
    } `json:"tags" form:"tags"`
}

type _customTime struct {
    time.Time
}
```

Create a structure as in the code above, and bind it as shown below:

```
d := &echo.DefaultBinder{}
var aa _getData
d.Bind(&aa, c)
fmt.Println(c.Request().Form)
fmt.Println(aa)
```

```
----- fmt.Println(c.Request().Form)'s result is -----
ap[address:[미국 캘리포니아 산타클라라 카운티 쿠퍼티노 ] date:[2021-10-01] location: 
[37.330672396748554 -122.03014377504589] pages[0][description]:[123123] pages[0] 
[order]:[0] tags[0][tag_name]:[sdf] title:[123123]]

----- fmt.Println(aa)'s result is -----
{123123 미국 캘리포니아 산타클라라 카운티 쿠퍼티노  37.330672396748554 -122.03014377504589 0 
2021-10-01 00:00:00 +0900 KST [] []}
```

The pages and tags data are not bound.
Other fields are bound, but why not just the multiarray field? How can I bind? I'm a beginner, any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: What `c.Request().Header.Get("Content-Type")` returns? And what data are you sending? From what I see I think Formdata, so why you specify json tag on struct?

Comment: The result of c.Request().Header.Get("Content-Type") is as follows.
multipart/form-data; boundary=--dio-boundary-4032587440
What do I need to do to get this data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Echo framework does not support binding array from form data out of the box.

You can use json instead or use 3rd party library. See [implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69449814/12301864) or [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54410886/12301864) and github issue https://github.com/labstack/echo/issues/1644

Comment: Meanwhile it is possible. Using it with `form:"value[]"` on Echo v4.6.3