# Ruby make put / post http call with array of object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http

i have this http call code, the type is form

```
      param = {
      form: {
      "creatives[]" => [
        {
          is_visible: params[:creative_banner_is_visible],
          type: "banner",
          value_translations: {
              id: params[:creative_banner_value_id],
              en: params[:creative_banner_value_en]
          }
        },
        {
          is_visible: params[:creative_video_is_visible],
          type: "video",
          value_translations: {
              id: params[:creative_video_value_id],
              en: params[:creative_video_value_en]
          }
        }
      ]
      }
      }

      http = HTTP.headers(headers)
      http.put(base_url, param)
```

but somehow this is translated to this on the target server

```
"creatives"=>[
    "{:is_visible=>\"true\", :type=>\"banner\", :value_translations=>{:id=>\"Banner URL ID\", :en=>\"Banner URL EN\"}}",
    "{:is_visible=>\"true\", :type=>\"video\", :value_translations=>{:id=>\"12345ID\", :en=>\"12345EN\"}}"
]
```

do you know how to make this http call not stringified? i used same schema on postman and work just fine

```
    "creatives": [
        {
            "is_visible": true,
            "type": "banner",
            "value_translations": {
                "id": "http://schroeder.info/elinore",
                "en": "http://wehner.info/dusti"
            }
        },
        {
            "is_visible": true,
            "type": "video",
            "value_translations": {
                "id": "85177e87-6b53-4268-9a3c-b7f1c206e002",
                "en": "5134f3ca-ead7-4ab1-986f-a695e69ace96"
            }
        }
    ]
```

i'm using this gem https://github.com/httprb/http

Answer (score 0, accepted):

somehow this approach fixed the issue

```
    create_params = {}.compare_by_identity

    create_params["creatives[][is_visible]"] = params[:creative_banner_is_visible]
    create_params["creatives[][type]"] = 'banner'
    create_params["creatives[][value_translations][id]"] = params[:creative_banner_value_id]
    create_params["creatives[][value_translations][en]"] = params[:creative_banner_value_en]
    create_params["creatives[][is_visible]"] = params[:creative_video_is_visible]
    create_params["creatives[][type]"] = 'video'
    create_params["creatives[][value_translations][id]"] = params[:creative_video_value_id]
    create_params["creatives[][value_translations][en]"] = params[:creative_video_value_en]
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

First, replace your `"creatives[]" => [ ...` with `creatives: [ ...` so the end result should be the following.

```
      creatives = [
        {
          is_visible: params[:creative_banner_is_visible],
          type: "banner",
          value_translations: {
              id: params[:creative_banner_value_id],
              en: params[:creative_banner_value_en]
          }
        },
        {
          is_visible: params[:creative_video_is_visible],
          type: "video",
          value_translations: {
              id: params[:creative_video_value_id],
              en: params[:creative_video_value_en]
          }
        }
      ]

      http = HTTP.headers(headers)
      http.put(base_url, creatives.to_json)
```

Second, I don't see any problem with what you get in your target server, you just have to parse it to JSON, so if you also have a Rails app there use `JSON.parse` on the body.

Comment: I have tried this approach but then resulting in the array modified to a hash

Comment: If you don't want a hash, then don't encapsulate `creatives` inside params. I updated my question and that should work now.

Comment: ```
http.post(base_url, param)
NoMethodError: undefined method `to_hash' for #<String:0x00007fdd72010cc8>
```
getting that error, and to get more context, this have similar problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34313657/html-form-post-an-array-of-objects

have tried that, but somehow it only send the last object of the array